# Mounting of NTFS drive failed, maybe due to windows hibernation

Tags: 14.04, windows, mount, ntfs

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/danny/70D49480D4944A6C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/danny/70D49480D4944A6C"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

thats what it said, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have Windows (maybe 8?) installed on your 4th partition (which is /dev/sda4 to Linux). Windows uses hibernation to fasten up its boot, but therefore stores RAM data and other stuff to its partition on the hard disk. This leads to your errors as Ubuntu can not properly access the drive due to Windows' lock. Boot into WIndows and disable the auto-hibernation feature and shut it down completely. Then you should be able to access the volume with Ubuntu. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can still mount the drive read only to access your data.

Create a mountpoint

> sudo mkdir media/danny/drive

and then mount it as read only

> sudo mount -o /dev/sda4/ media/danny/drive